# PIC18f4550 : Configuring RB4 for bi-directional data

Tags: pic

I am looking to configure my PIC so I can use port RB4 and send out pulses to a device and then receive data on the same port. For this I need to configure RB4 to be a digital I/O port and then;

set as output
lowsignal
1mS delay
highsignal
1mS delay
set as input
read input

This code then loops. So I have;

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++) // There are 10 bits of data to read
{
            ADCON0bits.ADON = 0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB4 = 0; // set to output
            ADCON0bits.ADON = 1;

            LATBbits.LATB4 = 0; // output low
            LATBbits.LATB4 = 1; // output high

    delay(1);

            ADCON0bits.ADON = 0;
    TRISBbits.TRISB4 = 1;   // configure for input
            ADCON0bits.ADON = 1;

    inData = inData<<1;
            delay(1);
    if (PORTBbits.RB4==1)
        inData++;
}
```

But I don't seem to be getting the inputs. I am new to the PIC world. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it possible to switch between input and output like this? Am I doing the right thing, the way I am configuring?

Many thanks!

Comment: When i am reading the description and then check your code, i see you don't wait 1 ms between output lowsignal and output highsignal.

Comment: Why are you flipping the ADC on and off rather than just leaving it off the whole time? If RB4 is configured as an analog pin I noticed you re-enable it before reading the pin, I think that's actually OK on most PICs but possibly not all of them.

Comment: This is a processor just awaiting to be fried. After you read your pin B4 state, there is only a few clock cycles before you set that pin to output again. If the other side happened to send a digital signal high,  you would be looking at a potential electrical short between the two devices!

Comment: Before you can even start you need to configure the ports as digital. For this chip, it's a bit complicated. Read the datasheet about register `ADCON1`

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late to the party. 
You are recommended to use interrupts in that part of code where you are awaiting for the data to be received. Polling is not generally a good approach, you will face much more complicated implementation rather than having a simple counter in the interrupt servicing routine.

So you should enable interrupt-on-change for 4th pin of PORTB.